# Joining against a CSV Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically there are 50 Custom Criteria which were done as a CSV column that corresponded to a table.

So say column CC5 with values '2,6,7,12,8,3,13,1,5,11,'

against a table `dbo.tbl_custom_code_5`

with values

```
code   desc
 1     Wine
10     Diet Pepsi
11     Other Soft Drink
12     Coffee
13     Tea ....
```

And so it goes ... So I need to do a group/count something along the lines of ...

```
 Select [desc], COUNT(b.CC6)
 from dbo.tbl_custom_code_6 a
 INNER JOIN dbo.Respondent b ON a.code = b.CC6
 group by [desc]
```

which obviously won't work due to the CSV, so I tried the first thing that came to mind.

```
 Select [desc], COUNT(b.CC6)
 from dbo.tbl_custom_code_6 a
 INNER JOIN dbo.Respondent b ON a.code like '%' + b.CC6 + ',%'
 group by [desc]
```

which doesn't work and wouldn't work even if it did because 6 would come up for 16 etc...

I know there has to be a better way to do this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this(I assume there won't be any spaces etc between , and numbers in the csv data):

```
SELECT [DESC], COUNT(b.CC6)
FROM dbo.tbl_custom_code_6 a
INNER JOIN dbo.Respondent b ON CHARINDEX(',' + a.code + ',', ',' + b.CC6) > 0
GROUP BY [DESC]
```

Comment: Virtual High Five, Very Cool ... I didn't know about this function in SQL.  This is comparing equality like contains in C# ?  So that would also mitigate the issue of the leading value having no predicate comma ?  Thanks again

Comment: Contains is similar to the `IN` clause. To avoid the issue with the missing predicate comma you can see that I am prefixing b.CC6 with a comma (`',' + b.CC6`)